# Midi Keyboard connected but no sound

Tags: midi, keyboard, reaper

I recently installed Reaper and have bought an Roland Um-One Midi cable to connect my Nord to the program.

I've installed the drivers, and now upon entering Reaper I've found that my midi keyboard is being recognised (when I hit notes, sound bars are moving) but I'm getting no sound.

I've selected a VST, have record monitoring on and selected the Um-One under all the midi settings- but alas, still no sound.

I'm using a Mac, does this have something to do with my sound card? I see a lot of other tutorials talking about using an ASIO driver, but I can't select anything like that.

I feel like I've tried everything! My computer is obviously reading the midi, but not giving me a sound.

Any help would be muchly appreciated!!

thanks

Comment: It's not clear yet if Reaper is not sending sound out to your hardware, or it's just not routing the audio from your VST correctly. What happens if you load a plain-vanilla audio recording into a Reaper track and hit play? Does it produce any sound then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/1109/how-do-i-configure-midi-in-reaper?rq=1

Comment: As stated in the answer of that question:  For an excellent guide on getting started with Reaper and MIDI [look here](http://stash.reaper.fm/7453/Art_of_Reabanks.pdf) (PDF).

Comment: Does your computer can play Midi without keyboard? (If you use normal windows player)

Comment: Do you have audio connected from your sound card to your speakers? Sorry if that seems elementary...you don't really describe your rig.

Answer (score 2):

In the audio preferences of Reaper check if you have the right sound card and output channels selected. If your midi keyboard is working correctly you should be able to have sound when using a standalone VSTi.